# How to sort values in column and update sequence number in the table row?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I want to sort data in a table by a certain column and assign a sequence number (position indicator) to every row according to the sort order. The table contains the following data:

```html
Id | result | position
---------------------------
1  |10| 1
2  |9 | 2
3  |2 | 3
```

Then I update the table data as follows:

```html
Id | result | position
---------------------------
1  |10| 1
2  |12 | 2
3  |2 | 3
```

After updating the result, I need to update the sequence number stored in column “position”.

```html
Id | result | position
---------------------------
1  |10| 2
2  |12 | 1
3  |2 | 3
```

Is it possible (using SQL only) to sort the data and at the same time update the “position” column? Actually I am looking for an answer to solve this issue using only SQL. If this is not possible I am going to sort and update the data using PHP. But I think this solution is not as good as using SQL only, because it will put more load on the system.

Comment: Was `2  |9`, became `2 |12`?

Comment: Yes was 2 | 9, became 2 | 12 So according new result 12 I need sort table and set the position for id:2 to “1”.